# ASP.NET razor capture session end

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, razor

In razor, we have _appstart and _pagestart.

Is there something like _sessionend that one can use to do work when a session ends without going to Global.asax?

Comment: When you say "when a session ends" do you mean when the *request* ends? Or do you really mean session?

Comment: The session. This question is mostly for curiosity. I do use the Global.asax file to handle my session stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_appstart` and `_pagestart` are specifically for hooking into page logic and data - they are not really for use with `Session`. They also don't have `_*end` counterparts.

To hook into session end you will have to use `global.asax.cs`, as one does with webforms.

Comment: I got no "global.asax.cs" in my VS 2019 .NET Core 2.2 application. I am familiar with this object in previous VB.NET and C# applications.

Comment: .NET core didn't exist in 2012... you wouldn't find that file in .NET Core.

Comment: Yes. But can I add it and use it's events? The OP was about capturing session end in Razor Page. Thanks.